# Stripe - Any way to migrate off older Charges API (Subscriptions) without creating a Customer beforehand?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am updating my billing page which used Stripe JS V2 tokens and the Charges API (Subscriptions).  The new(er) Payment Element looks slick from a future proofing standpoint, but am I understanding it correctly that the `Customer` object must be created prior to populating the payment form?

I only create the `Customer` once the payment token is obtained and a user has a clear intent to purchase after evaluating during a trial period.  Otherwise my Stripe Dashboard is overrun with "empty" trial users that never sign up (I only have around a 10% signup rate from account creation).  I guess this is mostly just a personal peeve, but I also just don't like to share user data and figured this way I would only be sharing with a third party once they become actual customers of mine.

Since a `Subscription` cannot be created without providing a `Customer` as part of the required parameters, am I stuck using the Card Element and the older Charges API if I don't create a `Customer` for every user in my system?

Answer (score 1):

You really should just create a Customer up front. It will be required if you want to use trials with Subscriptions and will be cleaner in the long run.

For a workaround, which I would not overall recommend, you could use a [SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents) with Payment Element to collect the customer's payment method without actually creating a Customer object. Then you can later create the Customer object and attach the PaymentMethod that was previously collected and then create the Subscription.